# Drop rows within dataframe based on condition pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Index Title'  : ["Company1", "Company1", "Company2", "Company3"],
    'BusinessType'     : ['Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 1', 'Type 2'],
    'ID1'     : ['123', '456', '789', '012'] 
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index = df["Index Title"]
del df["Index Title"]
print(df)
```

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NbKv.png)

where Index Title is a company name.
For Company 1 I have two types - Type 1 and Type 2.

---

For Company 2 I have only Type 1 
And for Company 3 I have only Type 2.

I would like to drop those rows where there is only one type - Type 1 or Type 2.

So in this case it should drop Company 2 and Company 3.

Could you please help me what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such problems we usually consider `groupby` and `transform` based filtering as it is pretty fast.

```
df[df.groupby(level=0)['BusinessType'].transform('nunique') > 1]

            BusinessType  ID1
Index Title                  
Company1          Type 1  123
Company1          Type 2  456
```

---

The first step is to determine the groups/rows which are associated with more than one type:

```
df.groupby(level=0)['BusinessType'].transform('nunique')

Index Title
Company1    2
Company1    2
Company2    1
Company3    1
Name: BusinessType, dtype: int64
```

From here, we remove all companies whose # unique types associated with are == 1.

Comment: What's the difference between `df.groupby('BusinessType').transform('nunique')` & `df.groupby(level=0)['BusinessType'].transform('nunique')`?

Comment: @PalimPalim Well, for one they're doing different things - level=... argument groups on a given level of the index. Well, level and axis together determine what you're actually grouping on, but axis=0 by default so it's usually the index.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:
- you group by `Index Title`
- filter if there is at least one `Type 1` & one `Type 2`

```
df = (
    df.groupby('Index Title')
    .filter(lambda x: (x['BusinessType']=='Type 1').any() & 
                      (x['BusinessType']=='Type 2').any())
    .reset_index()
)
```

---

Update if you are looking for two or more types regardless if they are Type 1 & Type 2

```
df = (
    df.groupby('Index Title')
    .filter(lambda x: x['BusinessType'].nunique() > 1)
    .reset_index()
)
```

In this case `@cs95`'s answer is the cleaner one, which you should use.

Comment: A couple of other points: 1) the way you build the condition with BusinessType is brittle - it means the code has to change if the contents of that column are any different. 2) I don't think this would work if there are more than two types.